# How to display constant values using custom-columns format of kubectl?

Tags: kubectl

I have multiple clusters and I want to check which ingresses do not specify explicit certificate. Right now I use the following command:

```
~$ k config get-contexts -o name | grep -E 'app(5|3)41.+-admin' | xargs -n1 -I {} kubectl --context {} get ingress -A -o 'custom-columns=NS:{.metadata.namespace},NAME:{.metadata.name},CERT:{.spec.tls.*.secretName}' | grep '<none>'
argocd               argo-cd-argocd-server    <none>
argocd                argo-cd-argocd-server                                <none>
reference-app         reference-app-netcore-ingress                        <none>
argocd                  argo-cd-argocd-server                 <none>
argocd         argo-cd-argocd-server   <none>
test-ingress   my-nginx                <none>

~$
```

I want to improve the output by including the context name, but I can't figure out how to modify the `custom-columns` format to do that.

Comment: what does `kubectx | grep -E 'app(5|3)41.+-admin' ` return ? (not a `kubectx` user)

Comment: Sorry, let me update the question.

Comment: Replaced `kubectx` with `k config get-contexts -o name`

Comment: one way is to dich the `custom-column` and use `jsonpath`, something like this: `k config get-contexts -o name  |  xargs -n1 -I {} kubectl  get ingress -A -o jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{} {.metadata.namespace} {.metadata.name} {.spec.tls.*.secretName}{'\n'}{end}" --context {}`

Comment: the other option is use bash looping to add the context to each line.

Comment: @P.... - although not using `custom-columns`, but still very close and I can use it instead. Could you arrange it as an answer so I could credit you and others find it more easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below command would Not yield the exact desired output, but it will be close. using `jsonpath`, it's possible:

```
kubectl config get-contexts -o name  |  xargs -n1 -I {} kubectl  get ingress -A -o jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{} {.metadata.namespace} {.metadata.name} {.spec.tls.*.secretName}{'\n'}{end}" --context {}
```

If the exact output is needed, then the kubectl output needs to be looped in the bash loop. Example:

```
kubectl config get-contexts -o name  |  while read context; do k get ingress -A -o 'custom-columns=NS:{.metadata.namespace},NAME:{.metadata.name},CERT:{.spec.tls.*.secretName}' --context "$context" |awk -vcon="$context" 'NR==1{$0=$0FS"CONTEXT"}NR>1{$0=$0 FS con}1'; done |column -t
NS       NAME                  CERT            CONTEXT
default  tls-example-ingress   testsecret-tls  kubernetes-admin-istio-demo.local@istio-demo.local
default  tls-example-ingress1  testsecret-tls  kubernetes-admin-istio-demo.local@istio-demo.local
default  tls-example-ingress2  <none>          kubernetes-admin-istio-demo.local@istio-demo.local
```

To perform post-processing around the header and context, the awk command was used. Here is some details about it:

Command:

```
awk -vcon="$context" 'NR==1{$0=$0FS"CONTEXT"}NR>1{$0=$0 FS con}1'; done |column -t
```

`-vcon="$context"`: This is to create a variable called `con` inside awk to store the value of `bash` variable(`$context`).
`NR==1`: Here `NR` is the record number(in this case line number) and `$0` means record/line.
`NR==1{$0=$0FS"CONTEXT"}`: This means, on the 1st line, reset the line to itself followed by `FS`(default is space) followed by a string "CONTEXT".
Similarly, `NR>1{$0=$0 FS con}` means, from the 2nd line onwards, append the line with `FS` followed by `con`.
`1` in the end is the tell awk to do the print.

Comment: Right now this is a script friendly output, `custom-columns` produce human friendly output. Can we format the output nicely with the header and tabulated output? Would you mind updating your answer to make it on a par?

Comment: @mark checkout the update.

Comment: That answers the question, but the last part with `awk` and `column` requires some googling.